# Each word editable when double clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, edit

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pydz7y6p/) I'm working on.

I like every one of the words in a paragraph to be editable in a textbox when the word is double clicked- and the word being uptaded with the new input when focused out (when clicked on a blank part of the page).

I tried it but had to use `<ul>` and `<li>` tags, which is not very practical. Also there are a couple of issues:

> -When there's more than one word in the textbox, it only shows the first word when double clicked. (Just try to edit the tag 'dolor sit
>   amet', it only shows 'dolor')
>
> -As double clicked, sometimes it selects everything (in blue), could not find a solution to that.
>
> -The size of textbox is not adjusted to the length of the word. Probably it's easy but I miss something.

Can you help me with those?

Comment: Use CSS `user-select: none` to disable selection of text when a user `dblclick`'s, this will get rid of the blue selection. Did you try adding `contenteditable` to your html-tags instead of JS? It's html build-in text-editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some issues are solved. You can refer this(I think this may be helpful to you).

> 1.When there's more than one word in the textbox, it only shows the first word when double clicked. (Just try to edit the tag 'dolor sit amet', it only shows 'dolor')

Use  `"<input type='text' value="+oriVal+">"`

> 2.The size of textbox is not adjusted to the length of the word. Probably it's easy but I miss something.

Find the width of selected `li` and apply that width to `text box`.

```
    var width = $(this).width();
    $(this).text("");
    $("<input type='text'    style='width:"+width+"px'value='"+oriVal+"'>").appendTo(this);
```

You can check the demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/pydz7y6p/4/).

**UPDATE**

As your requirements I updated the answer.

Depending on the `text` in `input box` the `width` of the `text box` should change on `keypress/keyup` event.

Also the `input box` should `focus out` on `enter` `key press`.

```
$("#parentUL").on('keyup','li', function(e){
     var width = $(this).width();
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $("input").focusout();
    }else{
       $("input").css('width',width);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Well thank you, but it doesn't still respond to the width of the input while typing. And hitting 'enter' should complete the editing (focus out) as well. Can you update the demo? I'd check that the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) `"<input type='text' value="+oriVal+">"` will become `<input type='text' value=word1 word2>"` if oriVal is `word1 word2`. See how you are missing quotes, and the browser will take word1 as the value of `value` property and treat word2 as a boolean flag property. Change it to `"<input type='text' value='"+oriVal+"'>"` and you'll be fine.

Yet, a better way would be `var ele = $("<input type='text'>");ele.val(oriVal)`. This will take care of all the quoting and escaping problems.

2) Just make your content unelectable. CSS `user-select: none` (you may need to add vendor prefix like `-webkit-user-select: none`) works on most modern browsers, there are tricks for older browsers.

3) This is not easy, especially concerning browser compatibility issues. Why not give a try with `contenteditable` instead of using a text input field. Almost every browser support it now.